# Error while processing route: Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, requirejs, amd

I'm getting the following error after upgrading Ember to the latest version:

```
Error while processing route: portfolio Cannot read property 'connectOutlet'
```

The error takes place whenever I navigate for example from:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/portfolio
```

to:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/publications
```

The weird thing is that if I refresh the pages many times sometimes it works and some times it's doesn't so feels like some file is loaded too late or maybe loaded twice.

**aplication.hbs**

The application view renders the header, footer and main container, which contains the application `{{outlet}}`.

```
<!-- ... -->
<div class="container" id="maincontainer">
  <div class="maincontainer">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

**index.hbs**

My index view renders a couple of subviews:

```
<div class="jumbotron fadeInUp animated">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="summary_content">
            {{view view.CvSummaryView}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**routes**
In all my routes I'm only adding the `model()` function. I'm not overriding `renderTemplate()` or anything else.

```
define([
    'Ember'
],
    function (Ember) {
        "use strict";

        return Ember.Route.extend({
            model: function()
            {
                var result = {};

                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: './website/js/models/portfolio.json',
                    success: function(data){
                        result.portfolio = data;
                    }
                });

                return result;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render({
        outlet: "main",
        into: "application"
    });
}
```

Do you have any ideas about what can be the root cause of this issue?

The entire app source code can be found at https://github.com/remojansen/remojansen.github.io/tree/master/website/js

**UPDATE 1**

I've been reading the Ember documentation and I added `{{outlet "main"}}` into my application template and tried with:

```
renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('blog', {           // the template to render
    into: 'application',          // the template to render into
    outlet: 'main'                // the name of the outlet in that template
  });
}
```

The I've been debugging the Ember code and I reached this function:

```
function appendView(route, view, options) {
  if (options.into) {
    var parentView = route.router._lookupActiveView(options.into);
    var teardownOutletView = generateOutletTeardown(parentView, options.outlet);
    if (!route.teardownOutletViews) { route.teardownOutletViews = []; }
    replace(route.teardownOutletViews, 0, 0, [teardownOutletView]);
    parentView.connectOutlet(options.outlet, view);
  } else {
    var rootElement = get(route.router, 'namespace.rootElement');
    // tear down view if one is already rendered
    if (route.teardownTopLevelView) {
      route.teardownTopLevelView();
    }
    route.router._connectActiveView(options.name, view);
    route.teardownTopLevelView = generateTopLevelTeardown(view);
    view.appendTo(rootElement);
  }
}
```

In the function above, in the line:

```
var parentView = route.router._lookupActiveView(options.into);
```

The variable `parentView` is `null` and `options.into` is `"application"`. So the line below throws an exception:

```
parentView.connectOutlet(options.outlet, view);
```

I have defined the application template and view but not an application route I don't know if that could be the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try naming your outlet as 'main' or just removing outlet property from render method?

Comment: @Vaibhav thanks for your suggestions, I have added an update to the question with more details please take a look, I hope it makes it easier to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time debugging I noticed that the ember `router._activeViews` element didn't always contain the `application` view:

**Works**

[image]

**Doesn't work**

[image]

I tried to analyse why was this happening and because as I said in the question:

> The weird thing is that if I refresh the pages many times sometimes it
>   works and some times it's doesn't so feels like some file is loaded
>   too late or maybe loaded twice.

I was almost sure that is was related with the usage of `require.js` and loading application components asynchronously.

The solution was use `deferReadiness()` and `advanceReadiness()`. Here is what I did in case it can help somebody in the future...

**app.js**

```
define(['Ember'], function (Ember) {
    "use strict";

    window.app = Ember.Application.create({
      LOG_TRANSITIONS: false, // basic logging of successful transitions
      LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: false, // detailed logging of all routing steps
      LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: false // detailed logging of view resolution
    });

    // Delay the app's initialization . We will invoke advanceReadiness()
    // when are ready for the app to be initialized
    window.app.deferReadiness();

    return window.app;
});
```

**main.js**

```
require([
    'website/js/app',
    /* routes, views... */
], function (
  app,
  /* routes, views... */
  ){
    "use strict";

    // Configure Routes
    app.Router.map(routes);

    // Set Routes
    app.IndexRoute = indexRoute;
    // ...

    // Set Views
    app.IndexView = indexView;
    // ...

    // We're ready to launch the app!
    app.advanceReadiness();
});
```